# Meteor template helper location

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

I have an app structured like this:

```
myapp/
myapp/client/index.html
myapp/client/lib/helpers.js
myapp/server...
```

Inside `helpers.js` I have:

```
Template.game.helpers({

    game_id: function() {
        return '12345';
    }

});
```

Inside `index.html` I have:

```
<div>
    Game: {{> game }}

    <template name='game'>
        {{game_id}}
    </template>
</div>
```

I'm getting these errors below and the page displays completely blank:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined
Uncaught Error: No such template: game
```

I'm using Meteor on Windows but I doubt this issue is Windows specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates need to be defined at the top level (outside of any other html tags). Change `index.html` to look something like:

```html
<body>
  Game: {{> game}}
</body>

<template name='game'>
  {{game_id}}
</template>
```

I'd recommend going through the [tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/try) on [meteor.com](https://www.meteor.com/).